# Use same session for each visit

Tags: asp.net, session

How can I use same session between user visits, if sessionState mode is SqlServer?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a persistant cookie when using [SetAuthCookie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.setauthcookie.aspx). The browser will resend the same cookie and restart the session.

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, true);
```

It's worth noting the persistant cookie will timeout after 30mins by default (in .Net 2 and above). You can increase this via the [timeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d3t3c61.aspx) attribute in the forms config.